# Making tabs change color after a click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working on a .net project and I have horizontal a tab menu. I want to change the background color of the tab I click on and reset all the other tabs to the default color using JavaScript. However, each time I click on a tab, the background color changes and when I release the the click, the background color goes away. Below is my code

```
 <div class="menu-control" id="SiteMenu" runat="server" visible="false">
                <ul class="routes-nav">
                    <li class="nav-tab  " onclick="setActiveTab(event)">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ARoute" runat="server" CssClass="tab-menu" OnClick="ARoute_Click">A Routes</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-tab" onclick="setActiveTab(event)">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="BRoute" runat="server" CssClass="tab-menu" OnClick="BRoute_Click">B Routes</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-tab" onclick="setActiveTab(event)">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="GRoute" runat="server" CssClass="tab-menu" OnClick="GRoute_Click">Grass Routes</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-tab" onclick="setActiveTab(event)">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="WRoute" runat="server" CssClass="tab-menu" OnClick="WRoute_Click">Watering Routes</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-tab" onclick="setActiveTab(event)">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="PRoute" runat="server" CssClass="tab-menu" OnClick="PRoute_Click">Planting Routes</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
    .tab-menu{
            display:block;
            border:1px solid var(--borderColor);
            border-top-left-radius:5px;
            border-top-right-radius:5px;
            background-color:var(--tabDefault);
            border-bottom:0;
            padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;
            color: black;
            
        }
.activeTab {
    background-color: var(--focusColor);
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function setActiveTab(tab)
{
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-tab");
    for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace(/\bacitveTab\b/g, "");
    }
    tab.currentTarget.className += " activeTab";
 }
```

Can someone help to see what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the parameter inside the function `setActiveTab` on `li` tag to `setActiveTab(this)`. `this` in this case means: current `li` tag.

```
<li class="nav-tab" onclick="setActiveTab(this)">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="ARoute" runat="server" CssClass="tab-menu" OnClick="ARoute_Click">A Routes</asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

Then, your js code should be:

```
function setActiveTab(currentTab)
{
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-tab");
    for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        var tab = tabs[i];
        tab.className = tab.className.replace(/\bacitveTab\b/g, "");
    }
    currentTab.className += " activeTab";
 }
```

---

You can also write it shorter:

```
function setActiveTab(currentTab)
{
    var activeTab = document.querySelector(".activeTab");
    if (activeTab) {
        activeTab.className = activeTab.className.replace(/\bacitveTab\b/g, "");
    }
    currentTab.className += " activeTab";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, I still get the same behavior. When I click on the tab the background color changes but when I release the click, the default color comes back. I was wondering if it is due to the postback that recreates the page from scratch.